# c# constructor overloading

Tags: c#

I created the following constructors for my class:

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{

    public AccountService(Meta meta)
    {
        Initialize(meta.DataSourceID);
    }

    public AccountService(string dataSourceID)
    {
        Initialize(dataSourceID);
    }
```

However when I call the class:

```
_accountService = new AccountService(vm.Meta);
```

I get the following message:

> Error 16  The best overloaded method match for 'AccountService.AccountService(string)' has some invalid 
>       arguments

Is there something basic that I am missing here? When coding intellisense gives me the two options and
there's no syntax error when I use intellisense to select vm.Meta? Do I need to declare constructors in the
interface?

Comment: What is the type of vm.Meta. If vm is an instance of Meta then pass **vm** instead of vm.Meta.

Comment: You in fact cannot declare constructors in the interface as a constructor is considered an implementation detail.

Comment: The type of vm.Meta is Meta.  Actually I tried something else. I completely removed the constructor and then let VS2010 generate a method stub. On compilation that still gives me the error. I'm even more confused now.

Comment: Does Meta implement any implicit casting operators?

Comment: All is ok. I couldn´t see anything wrong so I tried it and it compiles well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to declare constructors in the interface?

No.  You cannot decalre constructors in an interface.  Interfaces represent a declaration of your type's public api; they do not in any way specify **how** implementing classes are **created**

The code you have is correct, conceptually at least; the problem is likely that `vm.Meta` is not of type `Meta`, or a type that inherits from `Meta`.